# Communicating with .net via PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net, mysql, sockets

I have a .net winform application that I want to allow users to connect to via PHP.

I'm using PHP out of personal choice and to help keep costs low.

**Quick overview:**

People can connect to my .net app and start a new thread that will continue running even after they close the browser. They can then login at any time to see the status of what their thread is doing.

Currently I have come up with two ways to do this:

**Idea 1 - Sockets:**

When a user connects for the first time and spawns a thread a GUID is associated with their "web" login details.

Next time PHP connects to the app via a socket PHP sends a "GET.UPDATE" command with their GUID which is then added to a MESSAGE IN QUEUE for the given GUID.

The .net app spawned thread is checking the MESSAGE IN QUEUE and when it sees the "GET.UPDATE" command it then endcodes the data into json and adds it to the MESSAGE OUT QUEUE

The next time there is a PHP socket request from that GUID it sends the data in the MESSAGE OUT QUEUE.

**Idea 2 - Database:**

Same Idea as above but commands from PHP get put into a database

the .net app thread checks for new IN MESSAGES in the database

if it gets a GET.UPDATE command it adds the json encoded data to the database

Next time PHP connects it will check the database for new messages and report the data accordingly.

I just wonderd what of the two above ideas would be best. Messing about with sockets can quicly become a pain. But i'm worried with the database ideas that if I have 1000's of users we will have a database table that could begin to slow down if there is alot of messages in the queue

Any advice would be appricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either solution is acceptable, but if you are looking at a high user load, you may want to reconsider your approach.  A WinForms solution is not going to be nearly as robust as a WCF solution if you're looking at thousands of requests.  I would not recommend using a database solely for messaging, unless results of your processes are already stored in the database.  If they are, I would not recommend directly exposing the database, but rather gating database access through an exposed API.  Databases are made to be highly available/scalable, so I wouldn't worry too much on load unless you are looking at a low-end database like SQLite.

If you are looking at publicly exposing the database and using it as a messaging service for whatever reason, might I suggest [Postgresql's LISTEN/NOTIFY](http://codingzombies.com/coding/how-to-listen-to-postgresql-events-using-net/).  Npgsql has good support for this and it's very easy to implement. Postgresql is also freely available with a large community for support.